# Error broccoli-esnext is deprecated

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, frontend

Running examples from https://github.com/suchitpuri/emberjs-essentials/ . I'm receiving errors.

```
:~/ember-projects/emberjs-essentials/chapter-5/example1$ ember server
```

```
version: 0.1.4
invalid watchman found, version: [4.3.0] did not satisfy [^3.0.0], falling back to NodeWatcher
[deprecated] broccoli-esnext is deprecated. Use broccoli-babel-transpiler instead. https://github.com/babel/broccoli-babel-transpiler
[deprecated] broccoli-esnext is deprecated. Use broccoli-babel-transpiler instead. https://github.com/babel/broccoli-babel-transpiler
[deprecated] broccoli-esnext is deprecated. Use broccoli-babel-transpiler instead. https://github.com/babel/broccoli-babel-transpiler
[deprecated] broccoli-esnext is deprecated. Use broccoli-babel-transpiler instead. https://github.com/babel/broccoli-babel-transpiler
```

The ember server won't work properly. It starts but I never receive response from localhost:4200 keeping waiting for it. I checked code for existing references to broccoli-esnext. But it seemed to be called as the dependence not included directly in package.json. Can someone please explain how to fix this. Spent lots of time googling the issue but  with no luck so far.

Comment: those tutorials are very outdated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case it was because I had installed a version of ember-cli ages ago and it was still sitting there somehow overriding my fresh install of ember-cli.

I checked out the brocfile that looked like this(massive comments removed):

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var app = new EmberApp();
module.exports = app.toTree();
```

I checked out the required file, that only contained reference to the reccomended *broccoli-babel-transpiler*:

```
var Babel  = require('broccoli-babel-transpiler');
```

I started getting the hunch I was not using the newly installed ember-cli and checked the version of ember-cli:

```
ember -v
> 0.1.4
```

I had no idea what the current version of ember-cli was, but I suspected 0.1.4 was not it. I checked their site and found the version history:

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases

There was some steps to remove old ember-cli and update to current version:

1. npm uninstall -g ember-cli -- Remove old global ember-cli
2. npm cache clean -- Clear NPM cache
3. bower cache clean -- Clear Bower cache
4. npm install -g ember-cli@2.6.0-beta.2 -- Install new global ember-cli

I uninstalled ember-cli, and still:

```
ember -v
> 0.1.4
```

Cleaning the npm cache seemed to hang on my computer. But I removed the old ember-cli folders manually. I'm on windows and I had the
*ember* executable in:

```
c:\users\currentuser\Appdata\Roaming\npm
```

I also removed the ember-cli subfolder in:

```
c:\users\currentuser\Appdata\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

And again in:

```
c:\users\currentuser\Appdata\Roaming\npm-cache
```

After reinstalling ember-cli with

```
npm install -g ember-cli@2.6.0-beta.2
```

Everything worked perfectly!